# Azure node pool scaling using Azure Automation

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to accomplish the goal of managing cost of different azure resource groups, the project consists of several VMs and kubernetes clusters. To accomplish this goal I want to use the Azure Automation service, using this it's easy to shutdown and start VMs on a schedule.

So the problem is that I have not found a way to schedule squeezing each node pool of the K8s cluster down.

If any one can help doing this it would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shut down and start VMs of AKS cluster nodes pools on a schedule, you can schedule the resource group which the nodes in, not node pool. As I think, the node pool is just used to manage the VMs convenient. You can take a look at [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management). This way can manage the VMs inside a resource group.

Comment: In the resource group I have a Kubernetes  Services running. The node count is some value greater than 1 right now, I want to schedule it turn the node count down to 1 in the off hours and in the morning revert back to the node count greater than 1. Does this make sense?, Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Shadesfear Well, there is an autoscale for AKS, but if the requirement is not for that, you need to scale it manually via the script.

Comment: So yes  I answered my own question eventually, I needed to create the runbook (sciript) manually and schedule it manually aswell.

Answer (score 0):

To start and stop VM's it's done according to Charles Xu answer. To scale the Kubernetes cluster I needed to install the AKS module the in the azure portal and create my own runbook in the portal aswell. Invoking the AKS function as such

```bsh
Set-AzAks -ResourceGroupName <RG_name> -Name <K8s_names> -NodeCount <node_count>
```